# Python multiprocessing and shared memory - why do I get different results?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm testing some python code to share a numpy array between 2 processes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore, shared_memory
import numpy as np
import time

def reader(id, a, shm):
    exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm)
    b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=exst_shm.buf)
        
    time.sleep(2)    
    print('FUNCTION VERSION: ', b[0])   
    

def worker(id, a, shm):
    exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm)
    b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=exst_shm.buf) 
    b[0] += 10 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([0])
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes) 
    c = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    
    th1 = Process(target=reader, args=(1, a, shm.name))
    th2 = Process(target=worker, args=(2, a, shm.name))
    
    th1.start()
    th2.start()
    th1.join()
    th2.join()
```

The code above works fine and it prints out: FUNCTION VERSION: 10

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore, shared_memory
import numpy as np
import time

class Reader(Process):
    def __init__(self, id, a, shm):
        Process.__init__(self)
        
        exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm)
        b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=exst_shm.buf) 
        
        time.sleep(2)    
        print('SUBCLASS VERSION: ', b[0])   
       
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, id, a, shm):
        Process.__init__(self)
            
        exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm) 
        b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=exst_shm.buf) 
        b[0] += 10
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([0])
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes) 
    c = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    
    th1 = Reader(1, a, shm.name)
    th2 = Worker(2, a, shm.name)

    th1.start()
    th2.start()
    th1.join()
    th2.join()
```

However, when it's written as classes, it prints out: SUBCLASS VERSION: 0. Where does the difference come from and what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You create classes in wrong way.

Normally `start()` runs method `run()` to execute `target` in new process.

When you create own class then you have to overwrite method `run()` and put your code inside `run()` and then it will run this code when you use `start()`.

In your version it runs all your code in main process, not in new processes. First you create `Reader()` which sleeps 2s and prints result `b[0]`, and later you create `Worker()` which adds `b[0] += 10`. And after that you `start()` processes - but they have nothing to do because you didn't overwrite `run()` and you don't have `target` in classes.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore, shared_memory
import numpy as np
import time

class Reader(Process):
    def __init__(self, id, a, shm):
        Process.__init__(self)
        
        self.exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm)
        self.b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=self.exst_shm.buf) 
        
    def run(self):            
        time.sleep(2)
        print('SUBCLASS VERSION: ', self.b[0])   
       
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, id, a, shm):
        Process.__init__(self)
        
        self.exst_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm) 
        self.b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=self.exst_shm.buf) 

    def run(self):            
        self.b[0] += 10
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([0])
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes) 
    c = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    
    th1 = Reader(1, a, shm.name)
    th2 = Worker(2, a, shm.name)

    th1.start()
    th2.start()
    th1.join()
    th2.join()
```

---

**BTW:**

Using

```
import multiprocessing
print(multiprocessing.__file__)
```

you can find source code and see in `process.py` how it works.

```
def run(self):
    '''
    Method to be run in sub-process; can be overridden in sub-class
    '''
    if self._target:
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still get 0 when I run your code (Python 3.8.7 on Windows 10). Could you try running the code and see if it prints out 10?

Comment: I run this code before creating answer - and it works for me. But I tested it on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8.5.